# Calculating the algorithm complexity

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory, pseudocode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HbmFr.png)

Pseudocode
Can you help me finding out the complexity of the algorithm, as these j <-2j; i<-i+1 throw me out a bit.

Comment: I think it's `O(n^2)`  as nested while loops are there

Comment: Пожалуйста, не задавайте вопросы картинками. Текст вопроса должен быть в самом вопросе.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first consider the inner loop :

```
j = 1    
while j<=n
   O(1)
   j = 2*j
```

This loops runs for the values of `j = 1,2,4,8,...` while `j<=n`.
This loop will thus have logarithmic time complexity i.e `O(log n)`.

Now consider the outer loop :

```
i = 2
while i<=n
   O(1)
   //inner loop
   i = i+1
```

This loops run for the values of `i = 2,3,,4,...,n`

Thus outer loop have linear time complexity ,i.e `O(n)`.

So total time complexity `= O(n)*O(log n) = O(n*log n)`

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. It's the same logic when we get (log n) for certain sorting algorithms because they involve divide array into two sub arrays?